# How to fetch text in Textview field through JSON in android?

Tags: android

I am developing android application in which i have 12  Dynamic Frame layout in which Frame layout having Text view,video,and play/pause button over it .I want to fetch text in the Text view field by JSON. But my problem is that when i fetch text in Text view field using JSON text will appear in 12th frame and rest of 11 frame are empty.I don't know how to resolve this .kindly help me .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String moviename;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
VideoView vv;
TextView showingat, movie;
FrameLayout frame;
ArrayList<String> abc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigationbar);

    abc = new ArrayList<>();
    new Theaterflow().execute();
    //Main Relative layout.
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainRelativeLayout);
    //Main Scrollview.
    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    //Main Linearlayout.
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

    //Dynamically creation of Layouts.
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams playpausebtn = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams sound = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(55, 35);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams nowshwingat = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 60);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams movie_name = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60);

    //Defining array for framelayout.

    ArrayList fHolder = new ArrayList();
    int l = 12;
    for (int i = 0; i<=l; i++) {
        //Dynamically frameslayout for video
        fHolder.add(frame);
        frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 350);
        frameparams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);
        frame.setId(i + 1);
        frame.setMinimumHeight(350);
        ll.addView(frame);

        // Video over frames
        vv = new VideoView(this);
        vv.setId(i + 1);
        vv.setLayoutParams(frameparams);
        vv.setMinimumHeight(350);
        frame.addView(vv);

        //Pause btn over video
        Button pausebtn = new Button(this);
        pausebtn.setId(i + 1);
        pausebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        pausebtn.setLayoutParams(playpausebtn);
        playpausebtn.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        frame.addView(pausebtn);

        //Play btn over video
        Button playbtn = new Button(this);
        playbtn.setLayoutParams(playpausebtn);
        playbtn.setId(i + 1);
        playbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playy);
        playpausebtn.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        frame.addView(playbtn);


        //Sound btn over video
        Button soundbtn = new Button(this);
        soundbtn.setLayoutParams(sound);
        soundbtn.setId(i + 1);
        soundbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);
        sound.setMargins(0, 15, 5, 0);
        sound.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        frame.addView(soundbtn);

        //now showing at over video
        showingat = new TextView(this);
        showingat.setLayoutParams(nowshwingat);
        showingat.setText("Now showing at ");
        showingat.setTextSize(15);
        showingat.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        nowshwingat.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
        nowshwingat.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
        frame.addView(showingat);

        movie = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        movie.setLayoutParams(movie_name);
        movie.setId(i+1);
        movie.setText(" ");
        movie.setTextSize(15);
        movie.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        movie_name.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
        movie_name.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        frame.addView(movie);


    }


}

private class Theaterflow extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    // URL to get contents JSON
    String url = "http://filfest.in/demo/theater/first-theater-data.php";
    JSONArray contents = null;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls){

        ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonstr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, null);

        if (jsonstr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                contents = jObject1.optJSONArray("contents");
                for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c1 = contents.getJSONObject(i);
                    moviename = c1.getString("movie_name");
                    abc.add(moviename);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return  null;
    }
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        for (int i=0;i<abc.size();i++)
        {
            movie.setText(moviename);
        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: because you got only one instance of movie not the 11

Comment: Then how i make this

Comment: @nirajkumar You should figure this out yourself given the hint.

Comment: add tag to your textView then on your post execute call frame.getchildcount loop over them and check their tags and populate them according to tags

Comment: give me some code please

Comment: he Ahmed its shows empty Screen

Answer (score 0):

inside your for loop

```
movie = new TextView(MainActivity.this);      
movie.setTag(i);
```

insid your `onPost()` for loop

```
final int childCount = ll.getChildCount();

            for (int y = 0; y < childCount; y++) {
                final View child = ll.getChildAt(y);
                if (child instanceof FrameLayout) {
                    int childs = ((FrameLayout) child).getChildCount();
                    for (int j = 0; j < childs; j++) {
                        final View childViews = ((ViewGroup) child)
                                .getChildAt(j);
                        if (childViews instanceof TextView) {
                            final Object tagObj = childViews.getTag();
                            if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(i)) {
                                ((TextView) childViews).setText("Movie "
                                        + i);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: these code are all inside :for(int i=0;i<abc.size();i++){}

Comment: This gives me Empty screen

Comment: did you made the loop over your ll container ??

Comment: I tried the code and it worked fine , did you add the tag ??

Answer (score 0):

**Add view Programatically** in **LinearLayout**:

**layout.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity.java**:

```
LinearLayout llParent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llParent);
```

**onPostExecute()** of **AsyncTask**:

```
 for (int i=0;i<Your_ArrayList.size(); i++){
    TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
    txtView.setText(Your_ArrayList.get(i).getMovieName());
    llParent.addView(txtView);
 }
```

**Edit:**

```
 llParent.invalidate();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @nirajkumar, I have edited my answer, please check it